# Переменная со ссылкой на xml-файл

Tags: android, xml

Можно ли записать в переменную ссылку на *xml*-файл?

К примеру, на файл анимации `R.anim.alpha_anim`.

Если да, то какой тип должен быть у такой переменной?

Comment: Переменная типа int. это легко можно увидеть если посмотреть на параметры метода например `loadAnimation()` чую следующий вопрос будет как получить её :-) `getResources().getIdentifier()`

Comment: Точно, это было очевидно)